# How to make a Button execute different "classes' every button click

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a floatingactionbutton change a text widget every time its clicked, I have 3 classes and I want the ONE button to be able to call different classes every single button click and when it has finished calling the third class it goes back to executing the first class, and keeps on repeating..

I'm able to execute one class using the onpressed but im not sure how to execute different classes with every click..

Here's the code

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  void classes1(){
    setState(() {
      text = 'This is Text From Class1';
    });
  }

  void classes2(){
    setState(() {
      text = 'This is Text From Class 2';
    });
  }
  void classes3(){
    setState(() {
      text = 'This is Text From Class 3 ';
    });
  }

  String text = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text('AppBar'),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '$text',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: classes1,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your solution please checkout

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
int count = 0;
  void classes1(){
    setState(() {
      text = 'This is Text From Class1';
    });
  }

  void classes2(){
    setState(() {
      text = 'This is Text From Class 2';
    });
  }
  void classes3(){
    setState(() {
      text = 'This is Text From Class 3 ';
    });
  }

  String text = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text('AppBar'),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '$text',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          switch (count%3) {
            case 0:
              count++;
              return classes1();
            case 1:
              count++;
              return classes2();
            case 2:
              count++;
              return classes3();
            default:
              return null;
          }

        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```